# hi! I am trying to pass move_right interval to another in the same way move _left

Tags: jquery

i am try to clearInterval(move_left) which is in another function.The go_left is an variable which starts when i keydown :39(right arrow).When i keydown: 37(left arrow).

in the same way move_right interval.

```
$(document).keydown( (e)=>{
   var key = e.keyCode
if(key === 39){
clearInterval(move_right);
go_Left();
}

if(key === 37){
clearInterval(move_left);
go_Right();
}

 function go_Left(){
var move_left = setInterval( () =>{
console.log("clicked left arrow");
},40);
}

function go_Right(){
var move_right = setInterval( () =>{
console.log("clicked right arrow");
  },40);
}
```

Please try to understand the question and answer to me`enter code here`

Comment: You should use clearInterval for both objects in any button click otherwise if someone clicks same button twice or more times then it may break your functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reordered your code just like I would do it. Define variables in "global" scope, then your function-definitions and after that the keydown handler, should work like this, i didnt test

```
var move_left,move_right;

function go_Left(){
    move_left = setInterval( () =>{
    console.log("clicked left arrow");
    },40);
}

function go_Right(){
    move_right = setInterval( () =>{
    console.log("clicked right arrow");
    },40);
}


$(document).keydown( (e)=>{
   var key = e.keyCode
    if(key === 39){
        clearInterval(move_right);
        go_Left();
    }
    if(key === 37){
        clearInterval(move_left);
        go_Right();
    }
});
```

Always take care of the intendation, it helps you keep the overview